# Event Handler -- Cell not Updating as Expected

Tags: excel, vba

The code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim cell

For Each cell In Me.UsedRange.Columns("E").Cells
    If cell.Text = "Cu" And cell.offset(0, -1) = "WR229" Then
        MsgBox "Cu not permitted for WR229 or larger waveguide", vbOKOnly, "Cu Alert"
        cell = "Al"
    End If
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The problem is that when the condition is met the cell does not get reset to the value "Al". Why not?

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint on top of the loop and stepping through the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason the OP's code can fail is if the `UsedRange` does not start in column `A`.  This will occur if there is no data and no formatting at all in column `A`.

Why?  Because `.Columns` (and `.Rows` and `.Cells` for that matter) are *relative* to the specified range. For example if the `UsedRange` is `B2:Z10` then `Me.UsedRange.Columns("E")` will refer to range `F2:F10`.

Another issue in the OP's code is that it will run for any cells change, including those in Column `A`.  This will throw an error because Offset -1 from Column `A` is invalid.

So, how to fix it?  As answered by jbarker2160, you should take advantage of the `Target` parameter, which tells you which cells have changed.  However that answer leaves several problems.

- We want to check for Column `E` = "Cu" and Column `D` for "WR229", but we don't know which one will be entered first
- We should account for the possibility that several cells are changed at once, eg due to a copy/paste
- we should handle possible errors and *not* leave Events disabled
- The OP's code is case sensitive.  Ie "CU" will be accepted when "Cu" is not.  Is this the desired behaviour?  (If it *is*, remove the `UCase$()`'s from the code below)
- Implicit in the OP's code is that there is a range of *larger* waveguides that are disallowed for Cu.  This remains un-addressed in the code below.

This code addresses the above issues

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rw As Range

    On Error GoTo EH
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each rw In Application.Intersect( _
      Target.EntireRow, Me.UsedRange.EntireRow.Columns("D:E")).Rows

        If UCase$(rw.Cells(1, 2)) = "CU" And UCase$(rw.Cells(1, 1)) = "WR229" Then
            MsgBox "Cu not permitted for WR229 or larger waveguide", _
              vbOKOnly, "Cu Alert"
            rw.Cells(1, 2) = "Al"
        End If
    Next
EH:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Even better solution still. I did not know EnableEvents could be false. Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

## Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

If target = "Cu" And target.offset(0, -1) = "WR229" Then
    MsgBox "Cu not permitted for WR229 or larger waveguide", vbOKOnly, "Cu Alert"
    target = "Al"
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

## Explanation

Since you are doing this loop for each change, you don't need to loop through the entire column and using `target` will get around having to use the `Value` property.

Comment: aphoria's answer was helpful, and this goes one step further. Thanks for helping me with better coding practice.

Comment: After you solve your problem you should come back to the post and mark the most helpful answer as "The Answer."

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
cell = "Al"
```

To this:

```
cell.Value = "Al"
```